# how to change the color of date time picker in struts2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="birthDate" required="true"  
value="%{employee.birthDate}"      
displayFormat="%{#application.dateFormat}"/>
```

This is my date time picker tag in struts 2 used in **jsp**
            by default it has blue color 
            can any one help me to change the color of date and time picker
             i have used `cssStyle { Background:red }` which changes the color of textfield

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<sx:datetimepicker>` tag it means that you are using `dojo` plugin. You can change style of `datetimepicker` by using different `dojo` theme or overriding css styles associated with `datetimepicker`.

Comment: Are you loading correct css file? Inspect it in your browser.

Comment: after inspecting the changes i have made in correct .css file not take effect i have used eclipse indigo for runnig the project

Answer (score 0):

Please try this struts 2 uses default css so you can't so try the below link change only css as I mentioned.If you are using struts dojo avoid because it is deprecated.

[Link for datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
     <style>
      .ui-datepicker .ui-widget-content {        background: #999 none;  }
     </style>
```

Comment: .mydatebox{
       background-color:red;
      }  it changes the color of textfield not the calender

Comment: it works fine but problem using this that we can set dateformat like dd-mm-yy,dd/mm/yy,mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: ok then what you want to do with this date format ?, you want more formats or what ?

Comment: yes, in our project user can set the date format and store it in application scope  and this date format is reflected using tag displayFormat="%{#application.dateFormat}"

Comment: i have also used struts2 jquery plugin <sj:datepicker name="birthDate" displayFormat="{#application.dateFormat}"> getting error noSuchMethod Exception i thing it set the date in string format

Comment: you are changing your question very often ,you asked about color now you are asking about format ?

Comment: changing color affecting other functionality it is not good na