# Struts2 datetimepicker size

Tags: struts2, datetimepicker, dojo

I want to increase the size of the Calendar view because the default size is too small for my web application. I've tried to add a cssClass to the datetimepicker tag but it doesn't work, even if I change the width or height the only thing it changes is the field, not the calendar itself.

I'll put an image so you can understand better the problem that I have:

[image: datetimepicker problem]

The thing is that the text from the field is correctly viewed, but when I click the calendar button, it shows that tiny view and it's extremelly difficult to pick one date.

The code for the datetimepicker is this:

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="start_date" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="%{'today'}" />
```

Any guess?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13097880/1700321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, It's finally solved:

First I tried to find the file named `datefilepicker.ftl` inside the `struts2-core.jar` but I didn't find anything similar. 
So after a few hours trying to find which was the correct template of datetimepicker without any luck, I tried to solve my problem using JQuery because when I was searching for the answer I found out a [datepicker tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) using this library.

There's a plugin called [Struts2-JQuery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) that provides you with ajax functionality and therefore with multiple customizations in different widgets.

It's quite easy to install, I just had to download the correct .jar which for me it was Version 3.5.1 ( jQuery 1.8.3, jQuery UI 1.9.2 ). Once I'd downloaded the file, I just had to paste it in the lib folder inside my project. After doing that, I added this line at the beginning of the .jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

With these steps I had jquery functionality inside my .jsp file, so the only thing left to do is to add the datepicker widget:

First I chose the jquerytheme I wanted for my widget, just like this:

```
<head>
<sj:head jquerytheme="flick"/>
...
</head>
```

And then, I added my datepicker widget:

```
<sj:datepicker name="start_date" displayFormat="dd-MM-yy" value="today"/>
```

And that's it.

If you want to resize the datepicker calendar see the answer of this post:

[How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Answer (score 0):

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="start_date" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="%{'today'}" />
```

It is a dojo tag, so you should be changing the template file corresponding to this tag

**Freemarker changes**
check for something like datetimepicker.ftl in your workspace. That would be the file rendering your calendar. Any presentation related changes will be done in that file only.

**debug using firebug** 
Another approach can be using firebug in Mozilla firefox and manually try to change the html rendered by the tag. There might lie some CSS solution to your problem